# Add full version of jquery mobile to magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, mobile, requirejs

Magento2 loads by default a custom build of jquery mobile library:

```
deps: [
    "jquery/jquery.mobile.custom",
```

If I try to add the full version of the mobile library (require it in my theme):

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            fullJqueryMobile : 'Module/js/full_jquery_mobile'
        }
    }
}
```

then magento2 js functionality doesn't work (add to cart for example, but without errors in the console, just the page doesn't do anything), but the full library gets loaded and I am able to use the functionality. So there is a conflict somewhere.

How do I add it without breaking up magento functionality?